# Does `std::equal` dereference the `end()` in the case `abcd` and `abc`?

Tags: c++, stl

The implementation of `std::equal`, based on http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal, is the following:

```
    template<class InputIt1, class InputIt2>
    bool equal(InputIt1 first1, InputIt1 last1, InputIt2 first2)
    {
        for (; first1 != last1; ++first1, ++first2) {
            if (!(*first1 == *first2)) {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

When I compare `string str1 = "abcd"` against `string str2 = "abc"`, `equal(str1.begin(), str1.end(), str2.begin())`returns `false` as expected. Since `abcd` is one character longer, I wonder if the above implementation compared `'d'` against the `*str2.end()`. It seems like so, but isn't it unsafe? `str2.end()` may point to anything, and it might be `'d'`.

Comment: Looks like it doesn't it. I recommend using `equal( first1, last1, first2, last2 )` for ranges of unequal lengths.

Comment: You can't use the three argument version unless you, the caller, guarantee both ranges are the same length.

Comment: What do you mean by `end()`. Is that for `std::basic_string<T>`? Also, is it your intention to ask about the three-argument overload?

Comment: @Alf: He probably should say `end(str2)` instead

Comment: @BenVoigt: Well, the types matter here.

Comment: @BenVoigt: They don't really have to be the same length--it's fine if the second sequence is longer than the first.

Comment: @JerryCoffin that's true, but then it might declare that they're equal when they really aren't.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Right--but that's always the case. It only ever declares that the specific ranges passed are equal--using either the three- or four-iterator version, that can be a subset of a collection.

Comment: @JerryCoffin but I assume that if the sequences passed to the four-iterator version are different lengths, the result is always false.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Yes, if the ranges are of different lengths, the the result is false (but equal-length ranges drawn from different-length sequences can still compare equal).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about `std::string` or `std::wstring`, and assuming that you're talking about strings (like the literals in your example) that don't contain embedded nulls. Then:

Since C++11 dereferencing `end()` is in practice guaranteed to yield a null-char value also for non-`const` instance. And so the comparison stops there, because either it's different from the other string's value at this point, or it's the last iterator position.

C++11 §21.4.5/2
*about `std::basic_string::operator[]`*

> **”** *Returns*: `*(begin() + pos)` if `pos < size()`, otherwise a reference to an object of type `T` with value `charT()`; the referenced value shall not be modified.

There's a fine point here for language lawyers, that the null-value effect is defined for `operator[]`, which is defined in terms of iterators other than `end`, so that the `end` iterator in principle could be special cased.

But that would clearly be contrary to the intention of providing C string semantics to the degree possible.

Comment: There's nothing to stop a `std::string` from containing a null character within its valid sequence, so you can't assume the comparison will stop there.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Well, the OP's example that he's asking about involves literals with no embedded null characters. But thanks for mentioning that concern. I'll add an extra little qualification. Done. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In this case, you are comparing a five element array against a four element array (C-style and C++-style strings both have a terminating NUL character), and the fourth elements differ.

If you instead had

```
char str1[4] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' };
```

and

```
char str2[3] = { 'a', 'b', 'c' };
```

then your call would perform a read beyond the bounds (undefined behavior).

Comment: That the illustrative implementation will hit the NULs and terminate safely is true from C++11 onwards; in C++03 the string's internal buffers might not be kept NUL terminated, though in actual implementations they typically were.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does.  Thats why in C++14, the committee added a "four iterator" version of `equal` (and `mismatch` and `is_permutation`).

```
equal(s1.begin(), s1.end(), s2.begin(), s2.end())
```

will not dereference `s2.end()` (and can quickly return false if the ranges are different sizes, to boot!)